# How can I generate a large random token using PHP

Tags: php, random, cryptography, openssl

I want to generate a large (~2 kb), random, unique block of random text for use as an authentication token. Standard hashing functions produce results that are too short. Would it be OK to use openssl's private key generation function or is there more appropriate solution I should look at?

Comment: Why would an authentication token need to be that big?

Comment: Hashing doesn't add entropy, but 256 bits of entropy is "guaranteed" to be unique. You're unlikely to do any better with more bytes unless the algorithm you use actually has a large enough entropy pool; most don't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why you would need such a large string, but you should use the [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) function. It is generated with one of the strong encryption algorithms. That is about as random as you can get.